# How to make a list comprehension in python with unequal sublists

Tags: python

I have a list of unequal lists.
I would like to generate a new list with list comprehension from the sublists.

```
s = [['a','b','c','d'],['e','f','g'],['h','i'],['j','k','l','m']]
```

I am trying the following code but it keeps raising an indexError:

```
new_s = []
for i in range(len(s)):
    new_s.append((i,[t[i] for t in s if t[i]))
```

The expected output would be:

```
new_s = [(0,['a','e','h','j']),(1,['b','f','i','k']),(2,['c','g','l']),(3,['d','m'])]
```

Any ideas how to get this to work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) to iterate over each sublist elementwise, while using `None` as the fill value for the shorter sublists.

Then use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) to remove the `None` values that were used from padding.

So all together in a list comprehension:

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> [(i, list(filter(None, j))) for i, j in enumerate(zip_longest(*s))]
[(0, ['a', 'e', 'h', 'j']), (1, ['b', 'f', 'i', 'k']), (2, ['c', 'g', 'l']), (3, ['d', 'm'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

one without itertools but modifying the original list.

```
def until_depleted():
   while any(sl for sl in s):
    yield 1

list(enumerate(list(s_l.pop(0) for s_l in s if s_l) for _ in until_depleted()))
```

one without modifying the original but with a counter

```
idx = 0
max_idx = max(len(_) for _ in s)

def until_maxidx():
    global idx
    while idx < max_idx:
        yield 1
        idx += 1

list(enumerate(list(s_l[idx] for s_l in s if idx < len(s_l)) for _ in until_maxidx()))
```

A more explicit one without the inner comprehension nor calling generators:

```
ret = []
idx = 0
max_idx = max(len(_) for _ in s)
while idx < max_idx:
    ret.append(list(s_l[idx] for s_l in s if idx < len(s_l)))
    idx += 1

print(list(enumerate(ret)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is without itertools, but also without a comprehension, so I don't know if it does count as a solution.

```
s = [['a','b','c','d'],['e','f','g'],['h','i'],'j','k','l','m']]

new_s = []
for i in range(len(s)):
    tmp = []
    for item in s:
        tmp.extend(item[i:i+1])
    new_s.append((i, tmp))
```